# jxcore tasks vs nodejs clustur

Tags: node.js, jxcore

For providing multithreading node provides `clustur`. `JXCore`(fork of `node.js`) also claims they have provided multi thread. But if it was already there in node (as `clustur`) then what extra advantage does `JXcore` offers in terms of multi threading?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `jxcore` is not fork of `node.js`, but "a node.js distribution with additional features".
 Just like you don't call debian a linux fork. Debian could run with different kernels i.e. `freebsd` or `hurd` and `jxcore` could use both v8 (like node.js) and `spidermonkey` (from mozilla) as javascript engines.

`jxcore` was created when node.js doesn't provide multithreading and one of main goals was to add it. official description of its mt mechanisms you can find at http://jxcore.com/docs/jxcore-feature-multitasking.html. in my opinion launching mt from command line, without any changes in code, could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between Node.js clusters and JXcore multithreading is that clusters employ multiple **separate processes**, while JXcore threads are in fact **separate instances running under same single process**. That allows communication between threads to be somewhat faster than between clusters. Plus writing a code  for multithreadead tasks with JXcore IMHO is much more easier.

One of the early benchmarks can be found here: [JXcore vs Vert.x vs Node.JS Cluster](http://jxcore.com/nodejx-vs-vert-x-vs-node-js-cluster/)